# Inner Joins and Duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join 5 tables together, this brings back multiple duplicates of each row, sometimes the result set will be 150+ rows, which isn't expected, I expect somewhere between 5-7

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.user_name, a.date_added, a.guide_title, a.guide_summary, a.before_photo, a.after_photo, 
b.product_id,
c.step_number, c.photo, c.photo_caption, c.step_title, c.step_description,
d.tip_text,
e.product_name, e.page_address

FROM customer_stories AS a

INNER JOIN customer_stories_products_used AS b ON a.unique_id = b.story_id
INNER JOIN customer_stories_steps AS c ON a.unique_id = c.story_id
INNER JOIN customer_stories_tips AS d ON a.unique_id = d.story_id
INNER JOIN products AS e ON b.product_id = e.product_id

WHERE a.unique_id = 87
```

I have also tried GROUP BY, but this just brings back a single row

EDIT:
some info of what the expected results should be:

Each customer_story may have multiple steps (table c), multiple tips(table d) and multiple products used (table b), each of these products used should bring back some information from the products table (e).

each row returned brings back all of the data from (table a) which is always the same, and will also contain data from the other tables multiple times

Comment: Two comments: 1) You probably aren't getting "duplicate" rows back, but rather the rows in the result set _appear_ to be duplicate with regard to the particular columns you selected, and 2) Under the hood `DISTINCT` often uses `GROUP BY` as an implementation, so your above query might in practice already be a `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: If you could illustrate the problem by way of some sample data, maybe someone can shed more light on this.

Comment: Can you do a fiddle of your tables http://sqlfiddle.com/